# dumbster unit testing mail server does not return expected mail body?

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, jakarta-mail

i am writing the junit for email application that sends mail to any external domains like gmail etc. I am using dumbster(Fake mail server) apis for
that which includes class like SmtpMessage,SmtpServer etc. i am writing the junit where i am sending the unicode body

```
   String unicodeBody = "TestBody\u0393"
```

But when i receive it from Fake mail server i get it like this "TestBody=CE=93". Code for smtp server that receives the mail is

```
  SmtpMessage email=smtpServer.getReceivedEmail().next();
```

i am not sure what i am missing here?

just for information i send the mail as MimeMessage (whose content type is multipart/alternative) which internally
contains two mimeBodyParts i.e one for text body and another for html body.

**EDIT:-**
Complete email body is:-

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Message-ID: <18805827.1.1355311147338.JavaMail.SMiles@INN-L-0019>
Subject: subject
Date: Wed, 12 Dec 2012 16:49:07 +0530 (IST)
To: to@email.com
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
Reply-To: from@email.com
From: from@email.com

------=_Part_0_13986615.1355311147225Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
body=CE=93------=_Part_0_13986615.1355311147225Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
body=CE=93------=_Part_0_13986615.1355311147225--

------=_Part_0_13986615.1355311147225Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
body=CE=93------=_Part_0_13986615.1355311147225Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
body=CE=93------=_Part_0_13986615.1355311147225--
{MIME-Version=[1.0], Message-ID=[<18805827.1.1355311147338.JavaMail.Smiles@INN-L-0019>], Subject=[subject], Date=[Wed, 12 Dec 2012 16:49:07 +0530 (IST)], To=[to@email.com], Content-Type=[multipart/alternative;], Reply-To=[from@email.com], From=[from@email.com]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is called [Quoted Printable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) encoding, and you can decode it with [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/download_codec.cgi) for instance:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    QuotedPrintableCodec a = new QuotedPrintableCodec("UTF-8");
    try {
        System.out.println(a.decode("TestBody=CE=93"));
        // prints "TestBodyΓ"
    } catch (DecoderException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It will first turn `=CE=93` into the actual byte values `0xCE 0x93`, and then decode them as UTF-8 (Which was passed in the constructor)

Comment: I get the excpetion org.apache.commons.codec.DecoderException: Invalid URL encoding: not a valid digit (radix 16): 95
 at org.apache.commons.codec.net.Utils.digit16(Utils.java:44)
 at org.apache.commons.codec.net.QuotedPrintableCodec.decodeQuotedPrintable(QuotedPrintableCodec.java:186)

Comment: Once i give the complete body as mentioned in Edited part of question to a.decode i get not a valid digit error as mentioned in above comment

Comment: @emilly you just changed the question entirely.. of course it won't work because this solution was for `"TestBody=CE=93"` :P

Comment: That may work in some cases but it's not a solution. See Markus's answer. -1

Answer (score 1):

Today I came across this issue as well. To answer the question, you can't use the mail body with dumbster. Dumbster is [broken](http://sourceforge.net/p/dumbster/bugs/15/). The simple answer is use [greenmail](http://www.icegreen.com/greenmail/).

Answer (score 0):

To read the data in the returned message, use the MimeMessage constructor that takes an InputStream, then access the parts of the message in the normal fashion using the JavaMail APIs.  JavaMail will decode the encoded parts of the message for you.

Comment: But MimeMessage is not avaialble when i do smtpServer.getReceivedEmail(). I just get SmtpMessage which does not have anything where i can get message parts

Comment: Sigh.  dumbster doesn't really make this easy, does it?  You can use the toString method to get the entire message as a String, but then you need to create an InputStream based on that String, which you can use to create a MimeMessage.  Use the (deprecated) StringBufferInputStream.

Comment: You can simply avoid the deprecated StringBufferInputStream by using InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(yourString.getBytes());

Comment: Yes, at the cost of making a copy of the entire string data.  Probably fine for testing and small messages.

Comment: That's basically a good idea, but it doesn't work with Dumbster. See Markus's anwer. -1